# MySQL query fetch data

Tags: mysql

I've got a table ObjectDetails

```
objectId |   DeptID   |       workDate       |  percentage
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       1           06/07/16 10:10:10      10%
2       1           07/07/16 11:11:10      20%
3       2           06/07/16 09:10:10      5%
4       2           07/07/16 08:10:10      3%
5       3           06/07/16 10:10:10      15%
6       4           07/07/16 11:10:10      20%
```

Could you please help me to find a sql query that obtains the conditions ,
If i give input 2 then result query should return first 4 rows which means 2 departments .

Expected output:

```
objectId |   DeptID   |       workDate       |  percentage
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       1           06/07/16 10:10:10      10%
2       1           07/07/16 11:11:10      20%
3       2           06/07/16 09:10:10      5%
4       2           07/07/16 08:10:10      3%
```

If i give input 4 then result query should return first 4 rows which means 4 departments .

Expected output:

```
objectId |   DeptID   |       workDate       |  percentage
----------------------------------------------------------
1       1           06/07/16 10:10:10      10%
2       1           07/07/16 11:11:10      20%
3       2           06/07/16 09:10:10      5%
4       2           07/07/16 08:10:10      3%
5       3           06/07/16 10:10:10      15%
6       4           07/07/16 11:10:10      20%
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to always be starting from the first id and the deptids are conveniently grouped so maybe this will do

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key, deptid int);

insert into t (deptid) values
(1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(4);

select id,deptid
from
(
select t.id,t.deptid,s.maxid,s.rn
from t
join
(
select deptid, max(id) maxid,@rn:=@rn+1 rn
from t,(Select @rn:=0) r
group by deptid
) s
on s.deptid = t.deptid
) u
where u.rn <= 2;
```

result

```
+----+--------+
| id | deptid |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      1 |
|  2 |      1 |
|  3 |      2 |
|  4 |      2 |
+----+--------+
```